# Socket Programming in C/C++ - receiving a message defined by a typedef struct

Tags: c++, c, sockets, struct

A question about my socket program: I have a... inner class... I guess (sorry, coming from Java to C/C++) which is:

```
typedef struct {
    enum {Request, Reply} messageType;
    unsigned int RPCId;
    unsigned int procedure;
    int arg1;
    int arg2;
} RPCMessage;
```

I expect to receive an RPCMessage as the response to a request sent over a UDP socket. Currently, I receive the message with the code:

```
/* Recv a response */
fromSize = sizeof(fromAddr);
if ((respSize = recvfrom(sock, buffer, maxSize, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&fromAddr,
        &fromSize)) != messageSize)
    DieWithError("recvfrom() failed");
```

I should note that the buffer here is a char array. What I want is for the received message to be turned back into an RPCMessage... so I tried:

```
RPCMessage receivedMessage = (RPCMessage)buffer;
```

This is not making the compiler happy... What's the correct way to get those bytes in the char array arranged back into an RPCMessage and its fields?

Comment: You may want a pointer-type in front of that buffer. Casting to an object/struct definition is *almost* right.

Answer (score 3):

You have few options. Option #1 is to copy the contents of the buffer:

```
RPCMessage receivedMessage;
memcpy(&receivedMessage, buffer, sizeof(receivedMessage));
```

Option #2 is to re-interpret a pointer to a char buffer as a pointer to RPCMessage type:

```
RPCMessage *receivedMessage = (RPCMessage *)buffer;
```

And option number #3 is to manually parse the buffer into fields of class `RPCMessage`.

For options #1 and #2 you have to be aware of structure/fields padding, alignment requirements of your architecture etc.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're dealing with raw bytes, so use an unsigned char array, no accidental sign-extensions.

Second, you need a pointer type for referencing that buffer:

```
RPCMessage* receivedMessage = (RPCMessage*)buffer;
```

And lastly make SURE the sender AND the receiver are using the same byte-packing. Likewise, make SURE you received ALL of the data for your RPCMessage before doing the above.

Note: You're generally better off disassembling the bytes out of the buffer and manufacturing the received data in an RPCMessage structure unless you know for SURE both sides are agreeing on packing, endianness, etc.

Comment: Is there a good way to go about getting the fields one by one? When I constructed the message to send it, I set all the fields one by one using RPCMessage toSend = {RPCMessage::Reply, htonl(id), htonl(procedureId), htonl(firstArg), htonl(secondArg)} and I'd like to be able to make sure the enum is received correctly and that each (unsigned) int is received correctly with ntohl.

Comment: htonl etc surly helps with the endianness. The enum should be number based by you, but is obviously dependent on the compiler (ie. a 64 bit compiler *may* represent enums with 64-bit ints, whereas a 32bit one *may* differ. You already covered one of the harder parts; knowing a numeric value is how-many-bits wide etc, endianness, so on. the goal I simply tried to strike is that the only truly portable solution is to know, down to the very byte, exactly what each byte of data is and how it 'fits' into your structure. If nothing else I hope that is what you understood from it.